# Trouble with random image preload

Tags: html, image, vue.js, preloading

Hi I'm having trouble with image preloading.
I made a Vue app that shows a random image out of five images on the background.
I preload all five of them in my index.html.
Causing the following error :

```js
The resource someImg.jpg was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

This error is repeated four times. Which makes sense as four out of the five images are not used.
Does anyone know a way to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.